# Dynamically import class by name from module imported as:

Tags: python

I have searched high and low and can't find a proper solution.

I need to dynamically create objects and store them in dictionaries using a for loop from a class that is in a different file.

To avoid name space pollution I like to import my modules like so:

`from my_folder import my_file as mf`

the loop looks like this:

```
self.my_dict = {} # create empty dictionary

    for F in ('One', 'Two', 'Three', ...):
        object = F(var1, var2)
        self.my_dict[F] = object
```

on the line `object = F(var1, var2)` I need the `F` be referring to `mf.One`, 
 `mf.Two` and so on.

How do I append the value `F` to `mf` so it reads it as `mf.value-of-F` instead of reading it as `mf.F`?

I know I must be missing something very obvious, just not obvious to me right now.
Thanks

Comment: you can call `getattr(mf, F)(var1, var2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name)  What you're looking for is `getattr`.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `object` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `object` type.

Comment: Why not just use `for F in (mf.One, mf.Two, mf.Three)`?

Comment: What PRMoureu said should work, but there's probably a better way to organize your code. Eg, put the functions in the `mf` into a dict, with their names as the keys. Or just do it like Bryan Oakley suggests.

Comment: I did see the examples using `getattr` but they were using it to import a module from a class in a different file. Due to my newbieness, I want sure it applied to my scenario but could have tried I guess.

Comment: @Iguananaut. I did realize my question was almost identical to an existing one. I did have a look at it. I was just not happy with the solution given.

Comment: @PM 2Ring. I never use object as a variable in my actual code however, I did in my question to point out the obvious.  Thanks though;)

Comment: Understood. It's quite common for people to do stuff like that with list, str, dict, set, etc when explaining algorithms. But I don't think it's a good idea, since it often leads to conversations like this, and it could confuse innocent bystanders. ;) And of course, it's pretty rare that people need to use the `object` type explicitly in Python 3 code, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are almost certainly better solutions to your problem, but your example is so short and contrived that it's hard to give good advice.

To address the specific question you asked, you can use `getattr` to get a function or class from a module based on a string:

```
for F in ('One', 'Two', 'Three', ...):
    Cls = getattr(mf, F)
    obj = Cls(var1, var2)
    self.my_dict[F] = obj
```

A simpler approach might be to iterate over the classes themselves:

```
for F in (mf.One, mf.Two, mf.Three):
    obj = F(var1, var2)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. As always, simple, direct answers without wanting to be complicated.  I knew I was over  thinking this rather simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such syntax:

```
object = mf.__dict__[F](var1, var2)
```

Comment: Although this is necessary in some cases, it can be problematic, for example, if the object you're accessing is a descriptor.  This generally only makes sense if you have some reason to bypass the descriptor protocol, `__getattribute__`, etc. (which sometimes you do).